# Find derivative of function (matrix)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfy the condition $f(0)=(1,2)$ and $$Df(0)=
\left( {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array} } \right)
$$

Let $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $g(x,y)=(x+2y+1,3xy)$.

My question is how can I find $D(g \circ f)(0)$?

Comment: Using this notation, the chain rule is really easy: $D(g\circ f) = D(g)\circ D(f)$.

Comment: @Arthur i tried this but I was unsure about the calculations, can you please show me?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
    f(x,y,z)  &= (u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z))\\ 
    f(0,0,0) &= (1,2)\\
    g(u,v)  &= (u+2v+1,3uv) 
\end{align}\

\begin{align}
Dg(u,v) &= \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\partial _u}(u + 2v + 1)}&{{\partial _v}(u + 2v + 1)}\\
{{\partial _u}(3uv)}&{{\partial _v}(3uv)}
\end{array}} \right)
=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2\\
{3v}&{3u}
\end{array}} \right)
\end{align}\

$$
Dg(f(0)) = Dg(1,2) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2\\
{3 \cdot 2}&{3 \cdot 1}
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2\\
6&3
\end{array}} \right)$$

$$Df(0) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2&3\\
0&1&1
\end{array}} \right)$$\

$$D(g \circ f) = Dg \circ Df$$

$$Dg(f(0))Df(0) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2\\
6&3
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2&3\\
0&1&1
\end{array}} \right) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&4&5\\
6&{15}&{21}
\end{array}} \right)$$

Comment: Why is $f$ defined in each component with the same $u$?

Comment: @Lori: Second u must be v. It's a typo. Thank you.
Just edited.